# Pod Install Command Failed in Nativescript Project

Tags: ios, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

```
 I am migrating the Nativescript project in current version(8.1.5). I had pod install command failed issue while running the project. I added the error screenshot for your reference
```

[image]

Please help to fix this issue and save my time.